# After Plugin - Is it compulsory to return result?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, plugin, after-plugin

**Original**

```
public function addOrderCommentsTo($order, $prevOrder)
    {
        //something
    }
```

The original function doesn't return anything. Do I need to add return `$result` inside `Plugin after` function, what if I don't return anything?

**Plugin**

```
    public function afterAddOrderCommentsTo(RecurringOrder $subject, $result, $order, $originalOrder)
    {
        //something
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see in `\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor::___callPlugins:146`, return value of `after` plugin will be used as result for function.

```
foreach ($currentPluginInfo[DefinitionInterface::LISTENER_AFTER] as $code) {
    $pluginInstance = $pluginList->getPlugin($type, $code);
    $pluginMethod = 'after' . $capMethod;
    $result = $pluginInstance->$pluginMethod($subject, $result, ...array_values($arguments));
}
```

From PHP documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

> Note:
>
> If the return is omitted the value null will be returned.

It means that you should just **omit return** in your plugin in case of origin function return type is `void`.

You can use `return $result`, but this code will be incorrect after adding return type declaration to your function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

> A void return type has been introduced. Functions declared with void
> as their return type must either omit their return statement
> altogether, or use an empty return statement. null is not a valid
> return value for a void function.

```
public function afterAddOrderCommentsTo(
    RecurringOrder $subject,
    $result,
    $order,
    $originalOrder
): void {
    //something
    return $result; // Fatal error: A void function must not return a value
}
```